TIPS - BOX = CPI Call?
From what I understand a TIPS is something like a long position on the consumer price index (CPI-U specifically) with an embedded put (since you can’t get less than the original principle at issue) combined with a long treasury with face value $K$.
$$
TIPS = CPI + P_{CPI} + Ke^{-rt}
$$
Is that understanding correct? And if so, does it follow that by approximating a short treasury $-Ke^{-rt}$ by going short an SPX box spread (expiring on the same date as the TIPS bond matures) you would wind up with what is effectively a call on the CPI-U index?
$$
TIPS - Ke^{-rt} = CPI + P_{CPI} = C_{CPI}
$$
The way that the coupons of the TIPS are adjusted according to the principle would probably make it more complex than this, but is it the right idea? And how would those adjusted coupon payments affect the position if so?

You are conceptually right but your details are not accurate.  I would rephrase like this :
Suppose you buy a 5yr 2% Tips bond for 100 on the issue date , and you simultaneously sell a 5yr 2% Treasury with the same maturity.  (Which is not actually possible , because the maturities and coupons don’t line up , but we’re being conceptual here). Your net cash flows will indeed look like a call on cpi, being equal to $$max(0, cpi(payment date)/cpi(issue date) - 1)$$, applied to a 2% notional for each coupon payment and applied to the 100% notional at maturity.
A couple of observations about these call options : the market typically assumes that inflation will be about 2% per annum, whereas these options are struck at zero cumulative inflation since issue date.  Thus, the call options are deep in the money , especially in respect of the maturity date option.  This is reflected in the price of the options : you will find that you will sell the nominal bond for about 92 , so that you pay a net 8% for your options upfront (approximately equal to the PV of 2% per annum).
I’m unclear what you mean about the SPX.  Nothing here can be approximated by a stock strategy.

Thank you for the response. To address the last point: options on SPX are chosen simply because they are highly liquid and are European style (no early exercise allowed). The underlying ticker is unimportant, though. A box spread is completely delta-neutral—it is effectively a synthetic treasury zero. Any ticker will do. Going short a box spread is just the most practical way I can think of to approximate a short treasury. But any method of borrowing money near the risk free rate with the correct duration would work equally well.

Regarding going short a treasury with the same coupon—I don’t think that solves the coupon problem, because from what I understand each coupon is calculated based on the adjusted principle of the TIPS at the time of the payment, not the principle at time of issue.

Ok I understand the box idea; your second comment is incorrect actually.  Coupon put on tips is indeed 2% * adjusted principal but this is the same thing as 2% * original principal * cpi(cpn date)/cpi (original)

You're right. The coupons can basically be thought of like TIPS Zeros/STRIPS themselves so going short a treasury with the same coupon does have the desired effect. In practice (though unpractical) you'd have to go short a box for the size and duration of every coupon as well as the final payment. I'm going to mark this accepted, I appreciate the response.
